# Google App Script Sidebar Turns Blank from onclick

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-apps-script

**Code.gs**

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Procard Tracking');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

**Sidebar.html**

```
<style>
h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #949494;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.form-style-7{
    max-width:400px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.form-style-7 h1{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    font-size:x-large;
}
.form-style-7 ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
}
.form-style-7 li{
    display: block;
    padding: 9px;
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-7 li:last-child{
    border:none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.form-style-7 li > label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -19px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    color: #B9B9B9;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-7 input[type="text"],
.form-style-7 input[type="date"],
.form-style-7 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-7 input[type="email"],
.form-style-7 input[type="number"],
.form-style-7 input[type="search"],
.form-style-7 input[type="time"],
.form-style-7 input[type="url"],
.form-style-7 input[type="password"],
.form-style-7 textarea,
.form-style-7 select 
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.form-style-7 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-7 input[type="password"]:focus,
.form-style-7 textarea:focus,
.form-style-7 select:focus 
{
}
.form-style-7 li > span{
    background: #F3F3F3;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 -9px -9px -9px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.form-style-7 textarea{
    resize:none;
}
.form-style-7 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-7 input[type="button"]{
    background: #2471FF;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5994FF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #D2E2FF;
}
.form-style-7 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-7 input[type="button"]:hover{
    background: #6B9FFF;
    color:#fff;
}
</style>
<body>
<h2>Instructions</h2>
<p>Fill out the spreadsheet receipt information before filling out this section.</p>
<form class="form-style-7">
<ul>
<li>
    <label for="statment_date">Statement Date</label>
    <input id ="statementdate" type="date" name="statment_date">
    <span></span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="cardholders">CardHolder</label>
    <select id="cardholders" name="cardholders">

    </select>
    <span></span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="prepared_by">Prepared By</label>
    <input id="prepared_by"type="text" name="prepared_by" maxlength="100">
    <span>If different from CardHolder</span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="total_activity">Total Activity</label>
    <input id="totalactivity" type="text" name="total_activity" maxlength="100">
    <span></span>
</li>
<li>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
    <progress id="progress_bar" style="display: none; margin: auto;"></progress>
    <div id="finished" style="display: none; margin: auto;">
      <p style="font-size:22px; color: Green;">Ready to Print</p>
      <p style="font-size:16px; padding-top: 0px;">Go to File -> Print</p>
      <p style="font-size:12px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">(In the top left corner)</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

window.onload = setCardHolders();

function setCardHolders() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(cardHolders) {
      fillCardHoldes(cardHolders);
    })
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    })
    .withUserObject(this)
    .getCardHolders();
}

function fillCardHoldes(cardHolders) {
  var selectCardHolders = document.getElementById("cardholders");

  for(var i = 1; i < cardHolders.length; i++) {
    if (!isEmpty(cardHolders[i][0])) {
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = i+1;
      newOption.innerHTML = cardHolders[i][0];
      selectCardHolders.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }

}

function isEmpty(str) {
  return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

function submitForm() {
  var todaysDateString = new Date().toString();
  var statmentDate = new Date(document.getElementById("statementdate").value + " GMT-0800");
  var cardHolderDrop = document.getElementById("cardholders");
  var cardHolderRow = Number(cardHolderDrop.options[cardHolderDrop.selectedIndex].value);
  var preparedBy = document.getElementById("prepared_by").value;
  var totalActivity = Number(document.getElementById("totalactivity").value)

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        submitSuccessful();
      } else {
        alert("An error has occurred please contact spreadsheet owner.");
      }
    })
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      submitFailed(error);

    })
    .withUserObject(this)
    .submitted(todaysDateString, formatDate(statmentDate), parseInt(cardHolderRow), parseFloat(totalActivity), preparedBy);
  document.getElementById("submit_button").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("progress_bar").style.display = 'block';
}

function submitSuccessful() {
  document.getElementById("submit_button").style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById("submit_button").value = "Resubmit"
  document.getElementById("progress_bar").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("finished").style.display = 'inline';
}

function submitFailed(error) {
  document.getElementById("submit_button").style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById("progress_bar").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("finished").style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById("finished_info").innerHtml = "<p style=\"font-size:18px; color: Red;\">Failed</p><p>Please Contact Spreadsheet owner.</p> <p>" + error.message + "</p>";
}


function formatDate(date) {
  return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear()
}
</script>
```

This all used to work perfectly a weeek ago and I didn't touch it until these appeared. The input type date showed a dropdown calendar, and submit button worked and hide and showed html elements fine. This was without having to set the sandboxmode. However now the statement_date input which is of type date does not show a dropdown calendar anymore. Unless I set the sandboxmode of the sidebar to IFRAME. Which is fine but then when the submit button is clicked the whole sidebar goes blank and has no html what so ever inside of it what so ever. However the javascript still gets runs fine just the sidebar becomes blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're submitting to an empty page, that's why it's getting all blank, disable submit button with the code below and have you're own code handle the submit:

```
$('form button').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

And use the IFRAME, it's much better (unless you want to send files to the server).